# Having trouble using rAltmetric in R

Tags: r

Sorry new to stack overflow - but went back to some code using rAltmetric in R (used in in May), but now appears to not be working, have gone back and used some DOI and ISBN from previous comments on rAltmetric to illustrate new error I am receiving (tried also getting package from guthub) - I am wondering if they have closed the window to get into altmetrics

> library(rAltmetric)

> altmetrics(isbn = "978-3-319-25557-6")

Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
The API key you supplied was no
(right here) ------^

In addition: Warning message:

In altmetrics(isbn = "978-3-319-25557-6") : Unauthorized (HTTP 401).

> altmetrics(doi = "10.1038/465860a")

Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
The API key you supplied was no
(right here) ------^

In addition: Warning message:

In altmetrics(doi = "10.1038/465860a") : Unauthorized (HTTP 401).

Have others recently started having a problem with rAltmetric

Any help welcome.

MalcB

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear to be an API key problem. Something is up with their query function.

I created a simplified version of the function that works, here: https://gist.github.com/mathzero/f1d1b3b94f6f76019a5861d1bed7d597

... but haven't had time to identify exactly what the issue is.

In the mean time I suggest raising a query on their github.